# Using the 2022 Visual Studio react preview project template, how does the client communicate with the controllers

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I'm building an app using the react preview project that comes with Visual Studio 2022. I'm able to get it to run with the expected output, but I don't see how the client code communicates with the controllers. Here's the function in the App.jsx that calls the controller

```
     const response = await fetch('weatherforecast');
     const data = await response.json();
     this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
 }
```

and here's the controller code.

```
   public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
   {
       return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
       {
           Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
           TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
           Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
       })
       .ToArray();
   }
```

I would expect  const response = await fetch('GetWeatherForecast'); but that's not what it is. How does this work exactly?

Comment: Why do you think `weatherforecast` is wrong but `GetWeatherForecast` correct?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's in the vite.config. I see it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).